# How to clean resistors

Tags: cleaning

So I accidentally spilled milk on my resistor and I have no idea how to clean it. I wrapped the resistors with a towel but they still smell really bad :/.

Is it okay to put them in water and dry them with a towel?

Comment: As long as there's no voltage on it, almost any electronic component can be cleaned with soapy water. So just clean them properly with warm water and soap. Dry them properly afterwards and they will survive.

Comment: Uhm, what now, transistor or resistor? are they single components or is this a whole board?

Comment: Your resistors stink? Throw them away and buy new ones. They're too cheap to be worth cleaning.

Answer (score -1):

No...it's not ok at all.
Try 90° alcohol with some tissue and dry it with a hairdryer.

Water will not do anything good but possibly oxidizing the board's metalisations

Comment: Then please explain how the water will damage the transistors or why water is "not OK".

Comment: As long as you don't leave the PCB in water for hours and all batteries etc. are removed, there is no danger of oxidation. Also almost all PCBs have a solder mask to protect the copper anyway.

Comment: Yes but he also has a smell problem, so rubbing it in alcohol will be more efficient. Why not putting the board in the dishwasher in that case ?

Comment: Why is the smell going to go away just because alcohol is used to clean it?

Comment: Something about disinfecting stuff, removing organic material...you know...like what rubbing alcohol is meant for.